# Carousel overlaying background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, carousel

Soo... if anyone has a few minutes to spare and can take a look at my code and help me out here... I have a problem that I can't solve and have been busting my head for hours now...

So I'm making a page for a local intermunicipal Football Association using Bootstrap and I'm trying to achieve **this:** the carousel overlaying the background image, dont mind the blue and yellow thing...
[image]

and **this is what I get:**[image]

Here is my code:
**HTML:**

```
<!--Background image-->
  <div class="bg">
    <img src="img/football-field.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="ozadje">
  </div>

<!--Main content of page-->    
<section id="main-content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 navigation">
            content content
            content content
            content content
            content content
            content content
            content content
          </div>
          <!--Beginning of carousel-->
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-10 galery">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="desc">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="desc">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="desc">
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Left and right controls -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

and my **CSS:**

```
.bg{
  height: 420px;
  z-index: -999;
}

#main-content{
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: white;
}
```

I'd realy apreciate some help :)

**P.S.** I hope you understand what I mean and am trying to acomplish... English is not my native language so there may be some poor choice of words and bad exlenation and a lot of typos :)

Comment: could you provide the live url with actual content/images to debug simpler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set position value to your element so that the z-index works. It's either you use position `fixed, absolute, or relative`. Note that they are not the same and you need to add some css to it. Please see explanation [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) .

Sample:

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.start {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
}

.navigation {
  background: #F7F7F7;
}

#main-content{
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top:-1.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!--Main content of page-->    
<section id="main-content">
  <header>
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-american-football-players-in-the-action-grand-arena-345202907.jpg" alt="ozadje">
  </header>
        <div class="container start">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 navigation">
            content content
            content content
            content content
            content content
            content content
            content content
          </div>
          <!--Beginning of carousel-->
          <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 galery">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/950x250" alt="desc">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/950x250" alt="desc">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/950x250" alt="desc">
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Left and right controls -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using z-index only to display your content over your background image won't work.
In fact, z-index only works on an element with an absolute or fixed position.

The most easy and i believe most clean way to achieve what you want is to put your image as your page's background (with the css 'background' proprety).

```
#main-content{
background-image: url('img/football-field.jpg');
background-color: white;
}
```

An other way would be to make your section overlap the backgroung div.

```
#main-content{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not look very nice if you run it, but you can maybe get an idea from this code. Instead of using a div and insert an image (which pushes your div down) you could set a background image in css:

```css
#main-content{
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/Football_iu_1996.jpg/1200px-Football_iu_1996.jpg");
  background-color: white;
}

.item img {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--Main content of page-->    
<section id="main-content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 navigation">
            content content
            content content
            content content
            content content
            content content
            content content
          </div>
          <!--Beginning of carousel-->
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-10 galery">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="desc">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="desc">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="desc">
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Left and right controls -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

It is probably not exactly as you want it but it may be helps you to get on track.

Hope it helps a bit.